# анимация появления окна java fx (TRANSPARENT или UNDECORATED)

Tags: java, javafx

Когда делаю этот код с DECORATED или UTILITY, то все получается.

```
while (true) {
        double newOpacity = primaryStage.getOpacity() + 0.0032;
        if (newOpacity > 1) newOpacity = 1;
        primaryStage.setOpacity(newOpacity);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        primaryStage.show();

        if (newOpacity == 1) break;
    }
```

Постепенно появляется главное окно. Однако в TRANSPARENT не действует. Оно топорно появляется сразу же (переждав все sleep'ы). Хотелось бы сделать такой эффект именно с этим стилем. А если можно, то еще и укажите причину, почему он ждет все эти слипы, как он знает, что скоро его попросят сделать setOpacity снова. В этом деле новичок, прошу помочь. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = new StackPane( new Label( "Hello World!" ) );
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.initStyle( StageStyle.TRANSPARENT );
        primaryStage.setOpacity( 0 );
        primaryStage.show();

        Animation anim = getAnimation( primaryStage.opacityProperty() );
        anim.play();
    }

    private Animation getAnimation( DoubleProperty property ) {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame( Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue( property, 0 ) ),
                new KeyFrame( Duration.millis( 5000 ), new KeyValue( property, 1 ) )
        );
        return timeline;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

В `FX`ном потоке отрисовки крайне не рекомендуется делать какие-либо длительные действия (например операции ввода-вывода) и уж тем более искусственно тормозить поток `sleep`ами, иначе интерфейс будит тупо зависать и не реагировать на действия пользователей до завершения операций. Все подобное нужно выносить в отдельные потоки: для анимации придуман целый пакет `javafx.animation`, для длительных ожиданий `javafx.concurrent`; для простых действий можно просто отпустить поток, а в отрисовку вклиниваться с помощью `Platform.runLater( () -> //do_something )`.